# graphviz embed svg images

Tags: graphviz, cairo, dot

I am trying to generate a diagram with embeded svg images.
If I run graphviz with the regular svg command, the images are only referenced.

`dot -Tsvg diagram.dot -O`

[Here](http://www.graphviz.org/content/help-embedding-svg-files) it says to build with `-Tsvg:cairo` but I get the following:

`dot -Tsvg:cairo diagram.dot -O`

```
Warning: No loadimage plugin for "svg:cairo"
```

I have lib cairo installed, so I don't know what I am missing.

I am using ubuntu 12.04 LTS, I asked the same question in the askubuntu but there aren't any graphviz tags there.

Comment: Same on OS X High Sierra, latest `brew install graphviz --with-pango`.